# Can't access remote port 81 despite netstat showing it bound

Tags: linux, networking, bash, apache-http-server, firewall

I have an apache server with multiple `VirtualHosts` filtered by the `ServerName` directive. I am now attempting to have a `VirtualHost` filtered based a seperate port number, but am having issues.

My apache configuration is:

```
ServerRoot "/srv"

Listen ip:80
Listen ip:81

Include loadModules.conf

Mutex posixsem

<VirtualHost ip:80>
    Include external1.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip:80>
    Include external2.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost ip:81>
    Include external3.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Where `ip` is my remote ip address. In each externali.conf file, the `ServerName` directive is set to seperate domain names in 2 cases and in the third is set to:

```
ServerName ip:81
```

Connections via my browser, and via wget in bash work fine for the cases where the port is number 80. I get `connection timeout` errors in my browser trying to visit `ip:81`, and wget hangs in bash accessing `ip:81`.

Trying to diagnose the issue, I have checked the programs bound remotely with `netstat -ntlp | grep httpd` and the result is:

```
tcp   0   0   ip:80   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN
tcp   0   0   ip:81   0.0.0.0:*   LISTEN
```

Which leads me to the conclusion: (1) Apache is listening to incoming requests on ports 80 and 81.

Possibly there is a firewall blocking incoming connections, so I check firewall blocking with `ufw status | 81` returning an empty string, so I conclude: (2) there is no firewall blocking incoming connections.

By these results, I can't see why external requests aren't connecting.

Some other diagnostics which may help:
Running `wget ip:81` on my remote machine successfully returns a page.

I am running bash on Linux and my remote server is hosted with the IONOS company.

Any help pointing out where a potential issue could be or where I could have luck troubleshooting for the issue would be appreciated. Additionally, confirmation my assumptions (1) and (2) are correct would help my fire fighting.

I encountered this issue about a year ago and resigned to purchasing domain names in lieu of a fix - sorting this issue now would be most appreciated !

Comment: Assuming you've verified that ufw is active, did you use `sudo` when you checked for port 81?

Did you enable port 81 in ufw?  `sudo ufw allow from 0.0.0.0/0 proto tcp to any port 81`

Comment: The command `ufw status` returns `Status: inactive` so I conclude the ufw firewall is not active and thus not blocking any ports. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Comment: is it possible Ionos restricts by default the ports you're allowed to use to access your server?

Comment: Good call @pataluc   It may be network policies by the hosting provider.

I would go to your ionos control panel as described here:
https://www.ionos.com/help/server-cloud-infrastructure/firewall-policies/overview-firewall-policies/

Comment: Thankyou @pataluc and @ d-chord I am able to serve over ports aside from 80 by setting them as open in the IONOS GUI. As a follow up - can anyone comment on whether this is common industry practice, and if it is remediable via the command line ? I would personally prefer to set this myself without using an external GUI - thanks !

Comment: it is probably a default setting from Ionos, to allow only http and https to their servers.